# Break on NaNs or infs

Tags: c++, exception, floating-point, numerical, nan

It is often hard to find the origin of a NaN, since it can happen at any step of a computation and propagate itself.
So is it possible to make a C++ program halt when a computation returns NaN or inf? The best in my opinion would be to have a crash with a nice error message:

```
Foo: NaN encoutered at Foo.c:624
```

Is something like this possible? Do you have a better solution? How do you debug NaN problems?

EDIT: Precisions: I'm working with GCC under Linux.

Comment: There is such a thing as a signaling NaN which raises an exception at the hardware level. Maybe you can trap that somehow, but I never work that close to the hardware so no exact idea. But theoretically it should be possible as IEEE 754 explicitly includes that capability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it in a completely portable way, but many platforms provide C APIs that allow you to access the floating point status control register(s).

Specifically, you want to unmask the overflow and invalid floating-point exceptions, which will cause the processor to signal an exception when arithmetic in your program produces a NaN or infinity result.

On your linux system this should do the trick:

```
#include <fenv.h> 
...
feenableexcept(FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
```

You may want to learn to write a trap handler so that you can print a diagnostic message or otherwise continue execution when one of these exceptions is signaled.

Comment: To catch _all_ such exceptions, `feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);` .

Comment: For further readers: when debugging complex applications, the exception might occur in places that you are not interested about. In this case you can isolate only the pieces of code that you care about by combining `feenablexcept` with `fedisableexcept`

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Set (perhaps more or less portably) your IEEE 754-compliant processor to generate an interrupt when a NaN or infinite is encountered.

I googled and found [these slides](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/meeting-materials/2001-07-18-c99.pdf), which are a start. The slide on page 5 summarizes all the information you need.

Comment: Link is dead but available on webarchive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110611041908/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/meeting-materials/2001-07-18-c99.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C expert, but I expect the answer is no.

1. This would require every float calculation to have this check. A huge performance impact.
2. NaN and Inf aren't evil. They may be legitimately used in some library your app uses, and break it.

Comment: 1. I believe the CPU raises a flag when that happens. Since it is done in hardware, there shouldn't be a big performance impact

2. Sure, but for some applications they are :)

Comment: Regarding 1., it's done in hardware at no additional cost. 2. is a problem, but then again, simply changing the default round-to-even rounding mode to a directed one to implement interval arithmetic has this problem, so it's nothing new.